# Python: datetime, prevent time from turning into day,hour format when above 24hr

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

Let's say I have two times

```
import datetime    
x = '23:55:00'
y = '01:07:00'
```

When they're added together using:

```
x = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S')
y = datetime.datetime.strptime(y, '%H:%M:%S')
x = datetime.timedelta(hours=x.hour ,minutes=x.minute, seconds=x.second)
y = datetime.timedelta(hours=y.hour, minutes=y.minute, seconds=y.second)
z = x + y
```

the result is:

```
z = '1 day, 01:02:00'
```

Is there a way to make the result:

```
z = '25:02:00'
```

Comment: That's not a valid time format though?

Comment: So you want the number of hours, minutes and seconds between two datetime objects?

Comment: I'd like for the hours to roll over 24 if possible. I can use regex and some string manipulation to convert the final result but I was wondering if there's a straightforward way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the total hours for a timedelta object, you can call the `total_seconds()` method on your timedelta object and then use integer division to divide by the number of seconds in an hour(3600).

```
hours = z.total_seconds() // 3600
```